# Does jQuery AJAX work across different servers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I was using my localhost (MAMP) on my laptop the request worked just fine but when I moved my web application to a different server it doesn't seem to work returning the `error: function() { console.log("oh no");`. Code is below:

```
var backendURL = "http://dayout.uphero.com/dayout-app/php/";

.factory('AttractionService', function() {
     // Returns a JSON array

     var attractions;

     return {
     all: function() {

     jQuery.ajax( backendURL + "attractions_summary.php", {
                 async: false,
                 cache: false,
                 error: function() { console.log("oh no"); },
                 success: function(oData) {
                 attractions = oData;
                 }
                 });

     return attractions;
     }
     }
     })
```

Here is the attractions_summary.php file that connects with the server and returns a JSON array:

```
<?php

 include "../../config.php";

 header('Content-type: application/json');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

 $summary = mysql_query ('SELECT attraction.attraction_name AS NAME, attraction.image_name AS IMAGE, 
 attraction.attraction_price AS PRICE, attraction.id AS ID, bus.b_name AS BUSINESS FROM Attractions AS attraction 
 INNER JOIN BusinessInfo AS bus ON attraction.user_id = bus.user_id ORDER BY attraction.id DESC');

$result_formatted = array();
$i = 0;

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($summary)) {
$result_formatted[$i] = array();
$result_formatted[$i]['id'] = mysql_real_escape_string($result["ID"]);
$result_formatted[$i]['attraction_name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($result["NAME"]);
$result_formatted[$i]['attraction_price'] = mysql_real_escape_string($result["PRICE"]);
$result_formatted[$i]['bname'] = mysql_real_escape_string($result["BUSINESS"]);
$result_formatted[$i]['image_name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($result["IMAGE"]);
$i++;
}

echo json_encode($result_formatted);

?>
```

Comment: Have a lookup on Same Origin Policy

Comment: Look at the Javascript error console in your browser. Look at the Net tab in the developer tools - is the request being make to the right URL? Is the response what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Does jQuery Ajax work across different servers? - yes

```
[{"id":"4","attraction_name":"gerfwedq","attraction_price":"324","bname":"Texaco Garage","image_name":"icon-6013953941166125.png"},{"id":"1","attraction_name":"Starbucks Attraction Day!","attraction_price":"175.99","bname":"Starbucks","image_name":"footprints.png"}]
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

this is output from your url ...

remove following

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

I think this is added by hosting automatically

Comment: ye thats added by the hosting server... can't do anything about it.. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user3339063 — It is very invalid JSON.

Comment: after echo json_encode($result_formatted); use exit();

Comment: @user3339063 you can remove the last `x` chars from your response (where `x: length of string to remove`).